# Car accident in Germany: How to handle insurance claims?

Tags: germany, driving, insurance, poland

I had a car accident in Germany. It wasn't my fault and the claim is to be covered by the insurance of the person who was responsible. They accepted and so forth. The trick is I'm a Polish citizen and the insurance company here is represented by some partner.

Now  in Poland the insurance company has 30 days to wire you money when all the paperwork is fulfilled. However their Polish partner claims that the case is conducted under German law so the question is, how much time does a German insurance company have to pay up, is there a time limit, and if so, how long?

---

Okay since this question has spawned a very broad discussion, while the actual nature of the question was rather narrow, let me try to rephrase it.

How many days an insurance company in Germany has, according to local law, to pay money since claim was filled. For example: In Poland they have 30 days.

Thank you

If this edit won't help, please kill the question.

Comment: I'm a Canadian insurance broker so not deeply familiar with European insurance law, but in Canada, the normal tack here would be to claim with your own insurer and they would subrogate against (go after) the responsible party.  This would work as long as you have physical damage insurance on your vehicle.  You'd be out your deductible until recovery occurred, but at least not out the entire repair cost.  Is that practical here for you?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie, that’s the american way; in Europe, it’s not handled that way. If you are not at fault, the execution is between you and the other guy’s insurance; your own insurance has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Aganju "Europe" is a big place. In many individual countries within Europe, it works similar to Canada - you report it to your insurance company, and they deal with the other side, usually issuing funds to repair your vehicle in the interim.  The UK, for example, works this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Your insurance will have their process.

Comment: Usually a German car insurance will not pay any party directly. Instead, they cover repairs. In the simplest case, you let your own insurance pick where to repair your broken car, get a replacement car (or money per day) for the time being and at some point pick up or get the repaired car delivered. They'll mail you a copy of the invoices for your records in case you sell your car (or it gets stolen at a later point) and then settle, after which they'll try to get the money back from the other person's insurance.

Comment: @Moo the one time I've had a motor vehicle accident in the UK, it wasn't handled that way.  I retained my own solicitor on a contingency basis, who went directly after the other chap's insurance company.  So I'd beware of *any* broad-brush assertion about how things are handled, whether in a whole continent or merely a whole country.

Comment: @MadHatter I can assure you, that approach is *not* normal here in the UK.  Retaining a solicitor is exactly what you pay your insurance company for - and in general, Brits would very rarely deal with a solicitor in the UK, it's something we simply don't really do (based on the comments made by US posters elsewhere about getting stuff like employment agreements checked over). The normal approach here is to report it to your insurance, and they cover your own immediate costs and then go after the other side.

Comment: @MadHatter if you go for stuff like "knock for knock" or cash only agreements between parties without involving your insurance, you can get screwed for that as the other party has several years to then report any additional damage they want fixed, and you have no defence as you never reported it at the time.  This happens more regularly than you think - you agee to pay £100 for the damage to their bumper, but a year later they report the incident to their insurance company, claiming a brand new entire front end. Your defence is severely compromised as you never reported it at the time.

Comment: @MadHatter Disclosure - until recently I worked in the insurance sector, for a broker with claims authority.

Comment: @Moo The same issue happens in the US. People (with collision coverage) for some unknown reason try to take it up with the other party or their insurance themselves instead of subrogating the claim, often based on some false belief that their insurance will go up, or plain ignorance of their rights. The other side isn’t going to point it out. And you miss out on your underinsured motorist coverage. It’s definitely the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @user71659 One thing I *love* about the EU is that motoring insurance has unlimited liability coverage - you can't save money by getting a capped liability policy, if a claim means a £100million payout, that's what's going to be paid out (after the insurance company fights it as they would for any claim etc etc).

Comment: @Moo I've lived nearly my whole life in the UK, and done much of my driving there, so I'm not so in need of a primer on UK accident claims as you might think.  The main difference may be that I'm a motorcyclist, but whatever the difference, *nobody* I know who's ever had a UK accident that was primarily the other driver's fault would *dream* of leaving the settlement to their insurance company.  The exception is my brother-in-law, who ignored my advice to retain his own solicitor, and has since several times expressed his regret for that decision.

Comment: ...I understand that you've worked in the industry, and in the part of it that specifically deals with the mechanism of pressing the claims of their customers, but since we're considering here precisely people who've decided to ignore that mechanism, you may wish to consider that your viewpoint is no less biased by your experience than mine is by mine.

Comment: @MadHatter I understand hiring your own lawyer for a major injury accident, but, like the majority of accidents, what happens when the only issue is minor vehicle damage. You need to hire a lawyer for that? What an inefficient system!

Comment: @MadHatter my viewpoint existed well before I worked in the industry - you are definitely an outlier, not the norm in the UK. Everybody I know would leave it to their insurance company, not hire their own lawyer - hiring your own lawyer is ridiculous when you have already paid the insurance company to do that.

Comment: @Moo as I hope I've demonstrated, I'm not alone in my position.  I may well be in the minority, but we'll need actual data to determine that, not simply restated personal experiences.  user71659, as Moo says, nobody *needs* to hire a lawyer in the UK - but you are free to do so, if you don't think your insurance company's primary motivation is your own best interests.  Some do, some don't; I always would, provided I was reasonably sure the accident was the other party's fault (note that motorcycles tend not to have minor-damage-only accidents).  But as Moo says, many don't do it that way.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the [Deutsches Büro Grüne Karte eV](http://www.gruene-karte.de/de/unfallmeldung/) which is responsible for accidents which were located in Germany (!) and has at least one foreign person which belongs either to the EU or some other European country involved.

Select:
**1. *Der Versicherer des ausländischen Kfz ist mir bekannt*.**

*War der Unfall in Deutschland?* **Ja**
*Wo war das Kfz des Gegners zugelassen?* **B. Ausland**
*In welchem Land war das Kfz des Gegners zugelassen?* **Your country, in this case "Polen"**

Now select your insurance company and you get the contact details of the responsible branch in Germany.